# Hibernate with sqlserver deadlock issue

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, oracle, hibernate

Following are the two tables with its entity classes.

**tbl_rules**

| rule_id | rule_name |

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "db_user_name.tbl_rules")
    public class Rule implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @GenericGenerator(name = "incre", strategy = "increment")
        @GeneratedValue(generator = "incre")
        @Column(name = "rule_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private long ruleId;

        @Column(name = "rule_name", length = 250)
        private String ruleName;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "rules")
        private Set<Benchmark> benchmarks = new HashSet<Benchmark>(0);
        ... getters and setters
    }
```

**tbl_benchmark**

| benchmark_id | rule_id |

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_benchmark", catalog = "db_user_name")
@DynamicUpdate(value = true)
public class Benchmark implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "benchmark_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long benchmarkId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "rule_id", nullable = false)
    private Rule rules;
    .. getter and setters
}
```

Facing **deadlock** issue with `sql server db` in the following case

- `HibernateSessionManager.beginTransaction()`;
- call `saveRule(rule)` // in the backend rule and benchmark both tables
  are locked (using sql server locked tables query)
- call `saveBenchmark(benchmark)` // deadlock at this method
- `HibernateSessionManager.commit()`;

**Code where deadlock is happened:**

```
HibernateSessionManager.beginTransaction();
            UserIdManager.setCurrentGroupId(2);
            if (savingObjects.get(AmlConstants.USERCREDENTAILS_STRING) != null){
                    userCredentials = (UserCredentials) savingObjects.get(AmlConstants.USERCREDENTAILS_STRING);
                    Util.setAuditLogField(AmlConstants.USERIDSTRING);
                    this.getAmlDAOFactory().getUserCredentialsDAO().updateUserDetails(userCredentials);
                if (savingObjects.get(AmlConstants.USERBRANCHMAPPING_STRING) != null){
                    userBranchMapping = (UserBranchMapping) savingObjects.get(AmlConstants.USERBRANCHMAPPING_STRING);
                      Util.setAuditLogField(AmlConstants.BRANCH_STRING);
                      this.getAmlDAOFactory().getUserBranchMappingDAO().saveUserBranchMapping(userBranchMapping);
                }
            }
            HibernateSessionManager.commit();
```

**saveRule:**

```
@Override
    public Rule saveRule(Rule rule) throws Exception {
        try {
            getSession().saveOrUpdate(rule);
            getSession().flush();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        return rule;
    }
```

**saveBenchmark:**

```
@Override
    public Benchmark saveBenchMark(Benchmark benchmark) throws Exception {
        try {
            if (benchmark.getBenchmarkId() == null)
                benchmark.setBenchmarkId(getBenchmarkCount() + 1);
            getSession().clear();
            getSession().saveOrUpdate(benchmark);
            getSession().flush();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // logger.error("Runtime error while saving benchmark", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception while saving benchmark " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return benchmark;
    }
```

**Spring-Hib confg file:**

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" 
destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    ..
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                   <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.aml.hibernate.SQLServerCustomeDialect</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.character_encoding">UTF-8</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
                </props>
            </property>
    ..
```

**HibernateSessionManager.java**

```
public class HibernateSessionManager {

    public  static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HibernateSessionManager.class);
    public static final ThreadLocal<Session> currentSession = new ThreadLocal<Session>();
    public static final ThreadLocal<java.util.List<Session>> sessionList = new ThreadLocal<java.util.List<Session>>();

    /** Store transaction object on thread local
     * this helps to make a request processing transactional */
    public static final ThreadLocal<Transaction> transaction = new ThreadLocal<Transaction>();
    public static final ThreadLocal<Map<String, Transaction>> transactionMap = new ThreadLocal<Map<String, Transaction>>();

    /** keep the beginner method path which helps to commit on the same method only 
     * we are not supposed to make nested commits under a single request */
    public static final ThreadLocal<String> callerXPath = new ThreadLocal<String>();



    /**
     * Returns existing hibernate session binded with current request thread, 
     * if no session already bind with current thread then it will open a new session, bind to current thread 
     * and returns the session object
     * 
     * @param sessionFactory
     * @return
     * @throws HibernateException
     */
    public static Session currentSession(SessionFactory sessionFactory) throws HibernateException {

        Session s = (Session) currentSession.get();
        // Open a new Session, if this Thread has none yet
        if (s == null || !s.isOpen())
        {
            s = sessionFactory.openSession();
            currentSession.set(s);
            if(sessionList.get()==null)
                sessionList.set(new LinkedList<Session>());
            sessionList.get().add(s);
            logger.debug("Opened new session:"+currentSession.get().hashCode());
        }else{
            logger.debug("returning existing session:"+currentSession.get().hashCode());
        }
        return s;
    }


    /**
     * Closes all the sessions binded with current request thread
     * @throws HibernateException
     */
    public static void closeSession() throws HibernateException {
        currentSession.set(null);
        transaction.set(null);
        callerXPath.set(null);

        try{
            if(sessionList.get()!=null)
                for (int i = 0; i < sessionList.get().size(); i++) {
                    Session s = sessionList.get().get(i);
                    try{
                        if (s != null && s.isOpen())
                            s.close();
                        logger.debug("Closed session - session local:"+ (s!=null?s.hashCode(): ""));
                    }catch (Exception e) { logger.debug("Error while closing session: ", e); }
                }
            transactionMap.get().clear();
        }catch (Exception e) { logger.debug("Error while closing session: ", e); }
        sessionList.set(null);
        transactionMap.set(null);
    }




    // ------------------- Transaction management ------------------
    /**
     * Starts a new hibernate transaction on the session binded to current request thread
     * if there is already a transaction started on this thread, ignores creation of another transaction
     * all the db calls on a single request thread has to come under a single transaction
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean beginTransaction(){
        try{
            logger.debug("beginTransaction............... ");

            Transaction t = transaction.get();
            if(t == null && callerXPath.get()==null){
                Session s = currentSession.get();
                t = s.beginTransaction();
                t.registerSynchronization(new Synchronization() {

                    @Override
                    public void beforeCompletion() {
                        logger.debug("Transaction-beforeCompletion............... ");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterCompletion(int status) {
                        logger.debug("Transaction-afterCompletion............... "+status);

                    }
                });
                transaction.set(t);
                callerXPath.set(getCallerMethodInvolvedinTransaction());

                if(transactionMap.get()==null)
                    transactionMap.set(new HashMap<String, Transaction>());

                transactionMap.get().put(callerXPath.get(), t);
                logger.debug("Started new hibernate transaction:"+t);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error while starting new transaction: ", e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * if we already have a hibernate transaction created on the current request thread and some thing is committed on it
     * it will rollback the changes done after the transaction initialization
     */
    public static void rollback(){
        try{
            Transaction t = transactionMap.get().get(callerXPath.get());
            if(t != null){
                t.rollback();
                logger.debug("Roll back success on transaction:"+t);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception while trying to rollback", e);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Commits all the changes done after the transaction started on the current request thread
     * this accepts the commit command from the only method which started the transaction
     * This will unlink the current session and then currentSession() method can give another session as existing one is unlinked on the thread local
     */
    public static void commit(){
        try{
            logger.debug("commit............... ");

            Transaction t = transaction.get();
            if(t != null /*&& !t.wasCommitted()*/
                    && callerXPath.get()!=null && callerXPath.get().equals(getCallerMethodInvolvedinTransaction())){
                t.commit();

                currentSession.get().clear();
                currentSession.set(null);
                transaction.set(null);
                callerXPath.set(null);

                logger.debug("Commit success on transaction:"+t);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception while trying to commit", e);
        }
    }









    /**
     * get the caller method xpath: <package>.<classname>.<methodname>
     * @return
     */
    public static String getCallerMethodInvolvedinTransaction() {
        try{
            StackTraceElement[] stElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
            return stElements[3].toString().split("\\(")[0];
            /*for (int i = 3; i < stElements.length; i++) {
                String rawFQN = stElements[i].toString().split("\\(")[0];
                String className = rawFQN.substring(0, rawFQN.lastIndexOf('.'));
                String methodName = rawFQN.substring(rawFQN.lastIndexOf('.')+1);
                Object carObj = Class.forName(className).newInstance();

                ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
                CtClass cc = pool.get(className);
                CtMethod methodX = cc.getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
                int xlineNumber = methodX.getMethodInfo().getLineNumber(0);

                Method method = carObj.getClass().getMethod(methodName);
                if (method.isAnnotationPresent(JCTransaction.class))
                {
                    return rawFQN;
                }
            }*/
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("" , e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

But same working fine with `oracle db` (with oracle hib properties).

Comment: Provide the deadlock graph (available from the SQL SQL system_health extended event session), execution plans, and table DDL.

Comment: You have provided no evidence of a deadlock, including any error messages, stack traces or logging output that demonstrates a deadlock is occurring.  It is highly unlikely anyone can help you without more information.

Comment: @JimGarrison, I'm not getting any error at this stage, server is simply stucked as the benchmark table is getting locked (from db observation). I'm just restarting the server after this. I have updated the post by adding Hibernate session manager class

Comment: @JimGarrison, deadlock issue resolved after commenting `session.flush()`. Is it fine or will effect anywhere in future.

Answer (score 3):

There has to be something wrong with your code or you should never lock yourself out. Two different connections can block each other, but one connection should never block on its own locks. I haven't looked at the code in detail, I'll focus on why you get the problem with SQL Server and not with Oracle.

Oracle always uses versioning for rows, so rows are never locked just because they are read. SQL Server on the other hand normally takes read locks and a read lock will prevent writes from other sessions. You can probably change the SQL Server isolation level to READ_COMMITED_SNAPSHOT in order to hide the issue, but it will still be there.

I don't understand why you are clearing the session in several locations, that should almost never be done. I also don't understand all that code dealing with the transaction in HibernateSessionManager, that is probably the root cause of the issue. Somehow you're running with more than one transaction. Keep things simple instead and the issue is likely to go away!

Comment: deadlock issue resolved after commenting `session.flush()`. Is it fine or will effect anywhere in future.

Comment: But if I comment session.flush(), objects are not getting saved in oracle database :-(

Comment: Flush is not dangerous, clear is. If you remove clear the objects will be waiting in the session and flushed automatically. You will still get the locking problems if multiple transactions compete. Anything waiting to be saved (i.e. not already flushed) when you call clear is lost.

Comment: "You will still get the locking problems if multiple transactions compete." How to come across from this problem?

Comment: Sorry, How do I come out of this problem?

Comment: Hard to say exactly without your complete code, but I would try to get rid of HibernateSessionManager as much as possible. You can always get the current transaction with session.getTransaction(), so no need to keep track of it. Keep a thread local with the active session if you need to, but nothing more. Always open and close/commit in the same place. Then there should be a single open session with a single transaction per thread and things should work when you run single-threaded (i.e. with one user).

Comment: If you only get the error with multiple users/threads I have another theory. You are generating your ids with increment and by getting the next unused. That works great with one user, but if there are many users they are likely to compete for the same values and fail. Perhaps that is your problem? Use identity or sequence instead if you can, that may solve the problem without other changes.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, you already defined OneToMany relation between Rule & BenchMark. So while building Rule Entitiy / Object you build Benchmark too. Am I right?

**Analysis:** 
I am assuming Benchmark object is also populated and saved in Set Benchmarks. So right now you are saving Rule, as hibernate it will try to save Benchmark too. In same transaction you are trying to save Benchmark again and due to this transaction manager goes in deadlock situation.

**Solution:** 
Before setting benchmark in rule object try to populate benchmarkid and save only Rule which will save your behcmark object too.

```
@Override
    public Rule saveRule(Rule rule) throws Exception {
        try {
            //Get BenchMark from rule...
            // Your code to get Benchmark from rule.
            // Populate benchmarkId
            if (benchmark.getBenchmarkId() == null) {
                benchmark.setBenchmarkId(getBenchmarkCount() + 1);
            }
            getSession().saveOrUpdate(rule);
            getSession().flush();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        return rule;
    }
```

PS: Please refer Hibernate docs too.

Comment: Thank you, I will check with it

Comment: I have tested it with a simple application by creating two entities same as my main applicaiton. it is working fine with saving two objects in same transaction.

Comment: not solved. I tried to explain you that it is working fine with saving parent and child objects in a single transaction. "In same transaction you are trying to save Benchmark again and due to this transaction manager goes in deadlock situation." this is not the cause for deadlock.

Comment: Did you tried with only Parent which automatically save child too ?

Comment: Yes, But I can't add changes in existing project with only parent, because we don't where exactly will effect again in the whole application and we have separate calls to save only benchmark. So I'm trying with below user suggestion but no luck till today.